# How do I create a Sticky Nav bar that is centered and adjust to different screen sizes?

Tags: navigation, navbar, nav, sticky, graphical-logo

I am a newbie at this whole website thing for sure. I want to create a skicky navigation bar similar to the one on happycog.com/ I would like to have 7 or 8 links on the navigation. Can anyone help a noob out please?

Comment: Use Google to find a tutorial. We are here to answer specific questions; not to teach you how to make websites.

Comment: I also suggest google and learn, fiddle around with html and css too. I noticed that it wasn't included on this Post's tag and I'm assuming you don't know them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean css and html.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar">8 li items</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
```

You must give the containing element a width (or everything down from 'html' a 100%).

Comment: This worked, but now I need it to stay centered with the whole page no matter how big it gets. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean "page" not as happycog.com, check: http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/. This is actually something, which @craftein mentioned. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a framework like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html)

Or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

It's easier to get started with these as there are lots of documentation and the community is pretty large.

Answer (score 0):

First, realize that you need a container for all 8 links with a specified width like 980 or 1180 pixels. Also, it's important that its parent container (container which contains our links container) has a width of your browser's current length.

So let's say your links container is `<div id="links-container">` and contains
`<a href="#">Home</a><a href="#">Contact Us</a>` etc. And the parent of our .links-container is the body tag. -- That's all it for the html, now we go to the styling which we will use is CSS.

We'll style the container (with links) centered by giving it a style property (inline or in css)

```
.links-container {
    // this will make the container float
    // at the center of its parent container
    margin:0 auto;
    // this will set the container's width
    // if not set, it will inherit its parent's width
    width:980px;
}
```

Comment: It will inherit its parent's width! Well that's news ;) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp @goodvibedjs, check that site for tutorials and all references!